# Objective-C Convert String like '00120' into array of Integers

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to convert a string like '00120' into an NSArray of NSIntegers.

can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: So would this convert to the array `{ 0, 0, 1, 2, 0 }`?

Comment: Yes. An array of NSNumbers or NSIntegers, whatever will do.

Comment: Note that an array of NSIntegers would have to be a C-Array, it wouldn't be a NSArray (as NSInteger isn't an object, while NSNumber is).

Answer (score 6):

Try this code out:

```
NSString *input = @"00120";
NSMutableArray *integers = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    unichar c = [input characterAtIndex:i];

    if (!isnumber(c))
        [integers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1]];
    else 
        [integers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:c - '0']]; // convert the ASCII value to it's integer counterpart.
}
```

This is, of course, assuming all of your characters are numbers in the string.

EDIT: If you want a NSInteger, you need to make a C-Array:

```
NSString *input = @"00120";
NSInteger *integers = calloc(input.length, sizeof(NSInteger));
NSInteger integersLen = input.length;

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    unichar c = [input characterAtIndex:i];

    if (!isnumber(c))
        integers[i] = -1;
    else
        integers[i] = c - '0'; // convert the ASCII value to it's integer counterpart
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This works. What - '0' at the end stands for?

Comment: Read my edited post, with explanation of that and cases if the character is not an integer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a Java background so some things are ...not there yet :) . Your answer is perfect. Do I have do do anything besides choosing "accepted answer"?

Comment: You can up vote the answer if you'd like, it's always appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know can be found in the class reference for [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) and [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Look up a tutorial on `for` loops if you're not familiar with them already.

Notable methods that you're likely to want to use are `-length` and `-characterAtIndex:` on NSString, and `-addObject:` / `-insertObject:atIndex:` on NSMutableArray.

I don't mean to come across as patronising, but I'm not going to write out the code for you here as you'll learn much more if you work it out yourself with some help. Please do feel free to update the question with your code if you get stuck and ask for more specific help.

Comment: :) sorry, I forgot the post the code I already wrote. I'm traversing the input string and I get the current "digit" with characterAtIndex. When I'm trying to construct a Number with the int that I get, it actually constructs a Number with the ASCII value I think (for 0 I get 48). I'm doing something like: NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithChar:[inputString characterAtIndex:i]]